# Containment in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create switch buttons with on/off states(Using twitter bootstrap).

In this demo you can see that i have outer border to button. Button draggable is true to x-Offset.

I want button not to go out of my boundary. So i put it in a `div` element and set it to some width.
I don't think it is going good.

Please suggest me what can i do to bound this button in border area.

Fiddle link-
http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/w6AsC/3/

Some code shelf-

```
<div style="width:200px;border:1px dashed #ddd">
    <p id="button" class="btn-inverse btn">Regular link</p>
</div>
```

And script-

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $('#button').draggable({ axis: 'x' });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra parameter as explained in the [Docs, your friend and helper](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement).

```
    $('#button').draggable({ axis: 'x',containment: "parent" });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w6AsC/4/)

This way you theoretically don't even need the axis parameter.